# Regex substring in XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt

I'm trying to create a regex to get a substring in XSL 2.0 and this is the first time i'm working on XSL.

This is the expression that I'm trying to use to get the substring `/(GS\.?\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4})/g`.

If I get any other value like `GS.4354-4354-4543-5` or `GS.4354-4354-4543-556` I want to extract the value that matches my regex.

If I use 'matches' it is just returning true or false, but my expectation is to trim the additional data. Any help is much appreciated.

I've also tried the following

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$messageValue" 
       regex="(GS\.?\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4})">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <bug><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></bug>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

whereas my $messageValue = GS.4354-4354-4543-5 and it is giving empty response.

Input - XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
    <logentry revision="265">
    <author>dre</author>
    <date>2015-04-13T02:35:25.246150Z</date>
    <msg>GS.4554-0504-2089-4545</msg>
</logentry>
<logentry revision="73283">
    <author>john</author>
    <date>2015-04-13T14:10:20.987159Z</date>
    <msg>GS.4554-0504-2089-2</msg>
</logentry>
<logentry revision="73290">
    <author>ron</author>
    <date>2015-04-13T14:24:57.475711Z</date>
    <msg>GS-S.4554-0504-2089</msg>
</logentry>
</log>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>SVN Issues</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">ver</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">author</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">date</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">ticket</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="log/logentry">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@revision"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
        <td>            
                <xsl:variable name="messageValue" select="msg"/>
                <xsl:analyze-string select="$messageValue" 
                  regex="(GS\.?\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4})">
                      <xsl:matching-substring>
                         <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                      </xsl:matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output -

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>SVN Issues</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">ver</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">author</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">date</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">ticket</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>265</td>
            <td>dre</td>
            <td>2015-04-13T02:35:25.246150Z</td>
            <td>GS.4554-0504-2089</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>73283</td>
            <td>john</td>
            <td>2015-04-13T14:10:20.987159Z</td>
            <td>GS.4554-0504-2089</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>73290</td>
            <td>ron</td>
            <td>2015-04-13T14:24:57.475711Z</td>
            <td>GS-S.4554-0504-2089</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Solution from Martin is working when I test it in FreeFormatter.com, but for some reason when I deploy it on my cloud that is running linux this doesn't work. It is always returning empty string. Any one had any idea about it ?

Comment: Use `xsl:analyze-string` with `xsl:matching-substring` `https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-matching-substring` or if you use XSLT 3 there is an `analyze-string` XPath function.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Please see my edit. I've already tried what you mentioned, but it is returning empty response not sure what is wrong in it. Could you please verify and let me know.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] incl. input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rexeg` attribute can take attribute value templates which use `{}` as delimiters so to use the literally you need to double them

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$messageValue" 
       regex="(GS\.?\d{{4}}-\d{{4}}-\d{{4}})">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <bug><xsl:value-of select="."/></bug>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. I'll now try the non-matching string thing. I really appreciate the help.